# Space in HTML form input is replaced with a + in the URL. How can I get + to be %20?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I made the below HTML form, but the URL it creates replaces spaces with +.

```
<div class="well well-sm">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="http://example.com/init.html">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="nickname">Nickname</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="nickname" name="init_user" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="button"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need any spaces in the `init_user` text input to be replaced with `%20` rather than `+`. Is this possible using some JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need this? `+` is the correct character for spaces in querystring values, when encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Have you tried using php's urlencode()?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `init_user` is the nickname to enter with. `+` is a valid character so you're nickname would end up being `Rory+McCrossan` instead of `Rory McCrossan`, hence `%20` is needed.

Comment: @user3922663 that't not the case. The value will be decoded on the server side, so the `+` would be converted back to a space again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If it was then I wouldn't have opened the question. Users end up with the `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit your form using javascript. Before submitting the form create the URL manually and encode it.

```
function submitForm()
{
    var urlParam = "init_user="+document.getElementById("nickname").value;
    var URL = "http://example.com/init.html";
    var encordedUrl = URL+"?"+encodeURI( urlParam );
    document.location.href = encordedUrl;
}
```

change your HTML slightly as below

```
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="http://example.com/init.html">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="nickname">Nickname</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input id="nickname" name="init_user" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="button"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()" type="button">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```
var uri = "url.php?name=a &car=blue";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
```